# Unable to recognize the symbol

Tags: graphics, symbols

Can you please let me know what is this symbol [image]? I am trying to copy some text from a law book and this is in one of the setions.

Thank you

Comment: It means section, and is produced by `\S`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! Unless you're asking how to produce this in LaTeX, this is really kind of off-topic here, as this is TeX-LaTeX stackexchange.

Comment: You are awesome!!

Comment: I apologize. I am trying to create a latex document so thought this would an ideal forum.

Comment: See the app `detexify.`

Comment: No need to apologise. This is an ideal site for learning how to do things in LaTeX, slightly less ideal for general character identification! Anyway, as a general rule, the question I just linked to should be your first port of call for asking how to produce specific characters, as obviously a new question for every slightly rare character would be a bit tedious. If, however, you really can't find a symbol, absolutely, ask away :) (I checked and Detexify (first answer) definitely finds § - although it can't actually tell you what it means)

Comment: It is the typographical abbreviation of ‘paragraph’.